# Unix/Linux running complex commands over ssh

Tags: ssh, grep, find

I'm attempting to ssh onto a server then find todays files then grep within those files. But I'm getting an error, `` find: missing argument to `-exec' ``.

What am I missing here?

```
ssh server.name find /dir1/subdir/filelist* -maxdepth 1 type f -mtime 0 -exec grep 'pattern' {} \;
```

Comment: To supplement the answers here, it's worth pointing out that unless there's a reason why you want to run `grep` once for each file found by `find`, you should end that find command with `+` instead of `\;`.   If you don't want grep to output filenames, you can use grep's `-h` option.

Answer (score 10):

Problems with your code:

1. The local shell can expand `/dir1/subdir/filelist*` to one or more matching paths. These paths may or may not exist on the remote side.
2. The local `ssh` builds shell code (to run on the remote side) from multiple arguments it gets. The arguments are:

   - `find`
   - `/dir1/subdir/filelist*` (if there was no local match)
   - `-maxdepth`
   - `1`
   - `-type` (I assume your `type` is a typo)
   - `f`
   - `-mtime`
   - `0`
   - `-exec`
   - `grep`
   - `pattern` (because the local shell uses up the quotes)
   - `{}`
   - `;` (because the local shell uses up the backslash)

   And the built shell command is:

   ```
   find /dir1/subdir/filelist* -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime 0 -exec grep pattern {} ;
   ```

   This is not a valid `find` command because the (remote) shell will interpret `;` as command terminator and therefore `;` will never get to `find`. Also note the `pattern` is unquoted in the context of the remote shell.

I think this is the exact command you want to run in a shell on the remote side:

```
find /dir1/subdir/filelist* -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime 0 -exec grep 'pattern' {} \;
```

See [*How to execute complex command line over ssh*](https://superuser.com/q/1533956/432690) and my answer there. I won't repeat everything here. The most important thing:

> To be in control of what the remote shell will get as `$command_line_built_by_ssh`, you need to understand, predict and mastermind the parsing and interpreting that happens before. You need to craft your local command, so *after* the local shell and `ssh` digest it, it becomes the exact `$command_line…` you want to execute on the remote side.

A basic solution is to pass the exact (remote) command to the local `ssh` as a single argument. In your case the local command may be:

```
ssh server.name 'find /dir1/subdir/filelist* -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime 0 -exec grep '\''pattern'\'' {} \;'
```

In my answer to the linked question I discuss few more ideas.

Comment: `ssh server.name 'find ... -exec grep "pattern" {} \;'` should also do. Most regexes can do with just double-quotes (esp. since `"foo$"` keeps the `$` intact), and it avoids the need for the `'\''` dance.

Answer (score 6):

You are not running multiple commands with this ssh command, just a more complicated find command.

There are two main problems here.

- The way you write the command, the glob pattern will be evaluated on the client.
- The reason for the error message is that `;` doesn't reach the `find` command. Basically, `ssh` concatenates the arguments and passes them to `sh -c` on the server. You need something like `\\\;`.

Unless you need stdin on the server, the easiest solution is to send the command on stdin to a shell. This removes the need for quotes.

```
ssh server.name /bin/sh <<'EOF'
find /dir1/subdir/filelist* -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime 0 -exec grep 'pattern' {} \;
EOF
```

Comment: You can skip `cat` and just write `ssh sever.name /bin/sh <<EOF`. Also you missed the `type` mistype.

Comment: @JoL Fixed, thanks.