# pass variable to find files on remote server using newermt option

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I am trying to copy large number of file from remote server (serverB) to local server (serverA). I'm using the `-newermt` option in `find` to specify my time range.

I want to retain only 10 days worth of data on remote server (serverB). I use the following code:

```shell
a=10
b=9

x=$(date +%Y%m%d -d "$a days ago")
y=$(date +%Y%m%d -d "$b days ago")

echo $x
echo $y

#create a directory on local server

mkdir -p /fileData/fileBackup$x-$y  

ssh dbadmin@ip find /fileData/Backup -maxdepth 1 -name "*" -type f -newermt $x -not -newermt $y -exec cp -pr {}\;  /fileData/fileBackup$x-$y/
```

However, I'm getting the following output, ending in an error message:

```
20230512
20230513

find: paths must precede expression: 

Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

bash: /fileData/fileBackup20230512-20230513/: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unix/Linux running complex commands over ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/645430/unix-linux-running-complex-commands-over-ssh)

Answer (score 1):

Remember `ssh` runs a shell to interpret the concatenation with space of its arguments. That `*` needs to be quoted for the local shell and also for the remote shell, but `-name '*'` doesn't make much sense unless you want to exclude file names that are not valid text in the user's locale (but you'd like want to also check all directory components with `-path '*'` and not all `find` implementations would do that¹).

```
a=10
b=9
x=$(date -d "$a days ago" +%F)
y=$(date -d "$b days ago" +%F)
ssh dbadmin@ip "
  mkdir -p /fileData/fileBackup$x-$y &&
    find /fileData/Backup \
      -maxdepth 1 \
      -type f \
      -newermt $x \
      ! -newermt $y \
      -exec cp -pt /fileData/fileBackup$x-$y {} +
"
```

Also:

- `-r` doesn't make sense for regular files.
- With GNU `cp` (you're already using many GNUisms), you can use `-t dest` to specify the destination which allows you to pass more than one argument to `cp` without having to use `sh` to reorder arguments.
- I'd use YYYY-MM-DD format (as given with `%F`) rather than YYYYMMDD, as that's a standard format.
- See also `-mtime` in combination with `-daystart` as alternative to `-newermt` here.
- I'd recommend getting into the habit of passing options (like `-d spec`) before non-options (like `+%F`) as that's how the POSIX standard requires it be done, and even  GNU utilities which often allow options after non-options, they only do that when `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` is not in the environment. In any case, `-d` is not a standard `date` option.
- `cp` runs on the remote machine, so it can't copy file to your *local* machine. For that you'd need the remote host to send a serialisation of the files and their metadata like by using `pax` or libarchive's `bsdtar` or GNU `tar` and extract it locally:

```
a=10
b=9
x=$(date -d "$a days ago" +%F)
y=$(date -d "$b days ago" +%F)
mkdir -p /fileData/fileBackup$x-$y &&
  ssh dbadmin@ip "
    find /fileData/Backup \
      -maxdepth 1 \
      -type f \
      -newermt $x \
      ! -newermt $y \
      -print0 |
      bsdtar --format pax --null -cT - -f- |
      gzip -1
  " | bsdtar -C "/fileData/fileBackup$x-$y" -xpf - -'s:.*/::'
```

Here using `gzip -1` to compress the stream to save bandwidth. If on a low bandwidth link, you may want to use something that compressed better even if slower. If on a high bandwidth link, something that compresses faster, even if not as well. `gzip` is not very good on either front, but has the benefit of being almost ubiquitous.

---

<sup>¹ In the case of GNU `find` at least, that depends on the system's `fnmatch()` function it uses to match strings against filename patterns.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are trying to copy found files to the "/fileData/fileBackup$x-$y/" directory on the remote machine instead of your local machine (This is what your last line does), and the error is because there is no such directory on the remote machine, may be you can use scp to copy found files from the remote machine to your local machine.
Good luck.